# Convert string to 2d double array

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I want to convert string to 2d double array.My string is :"(-34.17141334413566, 148.1231689453125),(-34.371148707267096, 149.0130615234375),(-34.475366823896806, 147.919921875)". And the result is like
double[3][3] y = {{-34.17141334413566, 148.1231689453125},{-34.371148707267096,149.0130615234375},{-34.475366823896806, 147.919921875}}.I am new to java.help anybody thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your string?!

Comment: please, provide example string and what result is expected

Comment: please tell us how -34.17141334413566, 148.1231689453125 converted to 1,2,3?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (str is your input)

```
String str = "(-34.17141334413566, 148.1231689453125)," +
            "(-34.371148707267096, 149.0130615234375)," +
            "(-34.475366823896806, 147.919921875)";
str = str.replace("(", "");
String[] rows = StringUtils.split(str, "),");
double[][] doubles = new double[rows.length][StringUtils.split(rows[0], ", ").length];
for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
{
    String[] cols = StringUtils.split(rows[i], ", ");
    for (int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
    {
        cols[j] = cols[j].replace(")", "");
        doubles[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(cols[j]);
    }
}
```

Make sure there is at least one row (check it). StringUtils is an Apache Commons object, get its JAR for free from here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2

Comment: One thing should be edited:String[] rows = StringUtils.split(str, "),"); should be like String[] rows = StringUtils.split(str, ")"); otherwise all piece of code is fine. and thanks alot for help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to convert doubles data from a String (text file, scanner, ...)

You can use something based on that then :

```
Double[] array = new Double[2];
String s = "-34.17141334413566, 148.12316894531252";

String[] stringArray = s.split(",");
array[0] = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[0].trim());
array[1] = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[1].trim());
```

Be careful with Double.parseDouble(String s) and his exception.

And if I didn't understand the question, sorry ;)

EDIT : Of course my example is for a one dimension array, use a different character splitter for your second dimension.